# Deserialise string to an interface type without implementation C#

Tags: c#, json.net, discord.net

I am building an azure function to handle a discord bot with the interactions url endpoint. I am receiving the requests perfectly fine but I am struggling with converting the request body to the correct type. This is the code I am trying out:

```cs
[Function("InteractionHandler")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("InteractionHandler");


    DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    };

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation(requestBody);

    // Deserialize the JSON to a dynamic object (JObject)  
    IDiscordInteraction? data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDiscordInteraction>(requestBody, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = contractResolver });

    //more code here that uses the data...
}
```

So I know the req.Body will always follow the IDiscordInteraction interface as per [documentation](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/89efe0f3add3eee046ab3c8051652d8998746389/docs/guides/entities/glossary.md), so how do I use this code without getting following error:
`Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not create an instance of type Discord.IDiscordInteraction. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'app_permissions', line 1, position 19.)`

[image]

Comment: Deserialising creates an instance, and you can’t create an instance of an interface. Have you considered a base class which you could then cast?

Comment: @stuartd I have tried making a implementation class, but there are just so many properties that it felt like a waste and I felt like there was another way.. ill just have to implement it for all the interfaces on that glossary I guess?

Comment: Oh I effed up, I found out that the library has implemented classes, I guess I looked over them or the search didn't return it? real weird